# How to calculate the liability of laying a sports bet

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing an sql query to calculate the liability of laying a bet

The formula is:`

`Liability = (Backers stake * (Lay odds – 1)`

OR

`Liability = £1 * (1.32 - 1) = £0.32`

In SQL I tried:

`IF (1.0 * (rc.LayOdds -1), AS LayLiability,`

but  getting a syntax error, any suggestions?

-- // full query

```
SELECT   rc.ID,
         rc.RaceDate, 
         t.track.Name AS Track,
         h.NAME AS Horse,
         rc.LayOdds,

IF (1.0 * (rc.LayOdds -1), AS LayLiability,
  
FROM RaceCard rc

LEFT OUTER JOIN track ON track.ID = t.TrackID
LEFT OUTER JOIN horse ON horse.ID = h.HorsedID

WHERE (rc.RaceDate BETWEEN '2017-01-01'AND '2018-01-01')
;    
END
```

Comment: Hi Sir, Its easier if we see the whole script and also the error

Comment: In your script, you've got: `IF(10.0 * (A.BFSP-1), AS LayLiability`. It should just be `10.0 * (A.BFSP-1) AS LayLiability`. (You're also missing a trailing comma). But also, please include the actual syntax error, and the line it occurred on in the post.

Comment: May be you could try to ensure the query itself works before wrapping it in a stored procedure.

Comment: @mustaccio Yes, it works fine as long as I do not include `10.0 * (A.BFSP-1), AS LayLiability,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Change 10.0 * (A.BFSP-1), AS LayLiability` to `10.0 * (A.BFSP-1) AS LayLiability,`